# Has icon support in Windows 8 changed?

Tags: windows-8, icons

I am considering porting some of my favorite vector based icon sets to Windows, and was hoping to include support for Windows 8. Has Windows 8 changed the icon set format? Can I use SVG for my desktop icons?

Comment: You can also [change the Metro backgrounds](http://superuser.com/questions/493692/how-do-i-change-the-tile-image-of-a-modern-ui-application) if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows icons are still raster images. I believe InterfaceFormallyKnownAsMetro tiles can take SVG images though.

In application icons can be whatever the application framework handles and is largely independant of the operating system.

Comment: I've taken to calling it MUI - M standing for whatever Metro/Modern/Microsoft ;p

Comment: Thanks, I had heard that they could also be SVG. But now I am sad.

Comment: @Misha I've not heard that. If you find a reference, feel free to correct my answer.

Comment: Journeyman Geek: MUI refers to the Multilingual User Interface already, though :P

Comment: Some people would probably say it's a Messed-up User Interface. :)