# Change the Image/Logo of the Windows Store tile in the Windows 8 Start Screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I saw this post : [How do I change the tile image of a Modern UI application?](https://superuser.com/questions/493692/how-do-i-change-the-tile-image-of-a-modern-ui-application) but it didn't contain any method to change the image of the Windows Store tile.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Windows Store]

1. Navigate to `C:\Windows\WinStore` and make a backup of the `images` folder.
2. [Take ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) of the `images` folder.
3. Open the `images` folder.
4. To customize the normal tile, edit the `logo.png` and `logo.scale-x.png` files and to customize the wide tile, edit the `tilewide.png` and `tilewide.scale-x.png` files.
5. Open the Start Screen and make the size of the Store tile smaller or larger and you will be able to see the changes.

NOTE: This unique trick was discovered by me and is not posted anywhere.

Comment: Awesome hack! +100 if I could

Comment: Does this only affect the store tile?, any way to hack the other tiles included with W8?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/493692/how-do-i-change-the-tile-image-of-a-modern-ui-application